# asp.net mvc custom membership provider - strict login cache to one application

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I created custom membership provider for asp.net mvc applications and it all works fine except one thing:
when logged in to my application, I am also logged in to all other asp.net mvc applications that I run using Visual Studio. I suppose this data is being pulled from cache because when I logout and try to login again in other application, I'm being rejected.

In webconfig, I added applicationName in order to solve this but it didn't work:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SAMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add
          name="SAMembershipProvider"
          type="ShinyAnt.Membership.SAMembershipProvider, ShinyAnt"
          connectionStringName ="ShinyAntConnectionString"
          applicationName="MyApp"
          />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager defaultProvider="SARoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add
          name="SARoleProvider"
          type="ShinyAnt.Membership.SARoleProvider"
          connectionStringName ="ShinyAntConnectionString"
          applicationName="MyApp"
          />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Is there any method that I forgot to implement that is dealing with this problem or it is something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bit late for you, but maybe other people reaching this page may find this useful.

By default, forms authentication uses a browser cookie to save your authentication state, and they are scoped (and restricted) to a (sub)domain level (probably http://localhost/ in your case?).

This means that every application running under the 'localhost' domain root ( http://localhost/App1, http://localhost/App2) has access to the same authentication cookies.

you might be able to work around this issue by specifying a different cookie name per application in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="[cookie name]"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hey Zidad, I just saw your answer and things are much more clear now. Thank you!