# asp.net mvc membership - caches login info and shows on different applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-membership

I've asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919047/asp-net-mvc-custom-membership-provider-strict-login-cache-to-one-application) because I thought the problem was in my custom membership provider.

Then I tried this:

I created two NEW asp.net MVC applications. In first one, I registered as new user using default membership provider. I closed this application, opened second one and ran it. In this application I was also logged in as user I created in first application. Logging in as user from other application doesn't work, but caching is remembered on this site. Why is it so? Is it a bug?

Comment: "I closed this application, opened second one and ran it"  All in the same browser?  Which browser where you using?  Did you cookies left over from the first application?  Did you clear cache and remove cookies?  Please update the question with additional information.

Comment: The same browser (Firefox) and I didn't clear cache and cookies. But why is it interfering with other applications? Shouldn't each application be unique?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because when I open other site where I have implemented my custom membership provider, logic depends on this data and then I get error because of inconsistent data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be expected behaviour:

If you open localhost/app1 and localhost/app2 you are on the same domain. So its valid that the same cookie is sent. I am not shure if localhost:5050 localhost:5060 are considered as the same domain. But I guess thats the case.

If the same cookie is sent the Memebershipsystem will evaluate this as the same user. Thats expected behaviour.

If you want to have these 2 webs use different pools of users you have to create a new application in the Mebershipsystem and configure it in web.config.

This will not affect the behaviour of a production system, because the 2 web will be on a different domain. each domain is only allowed to access its own cookies.

Comment: So, if I have two apps (two different domains) on same server using two different pools, you're saying that this behavior shouldn't appear?

Comment: Yes, but this is just an educated guess